# Execute a git pull on a remote windows server

Tags: windows, git, powershell-v3.0

I'm trying to remotely execute a `git pull` on a Windows server via `New-PSSession` powershell script. Most git commands like status and help, but when I execute a pull command it just hangs and I confirm that the process is just waiting on the remote server.

I believe it's actually the `git fetch` command that is hanging. I'm using msysgit 1.9.4 15/aug/2014 release.

Does anyone have any other methods of executing a `git pull` on a Windows server without RDPing into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 days trying to get this to work and trying older version of msysgit I gave up and setup an OpenSSH server on the windows box and I simply execute my commands over SSH. It was much simpler to set this up and getting it working instead of doing it over powershell.